# Getting a "Did not expect..." error when trying to test uniqueness validation using shoulda-matchers/RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm still new to testing in Rails apps and I'm trying to add some basic tests to one of my apps models.  To be more specific, I'm using the shoulda-matchers 3.0.1 and rspec-rails 3.4.0 gems.  My test is as follows:

```
RSpec.describe User, type: :model do
  describe 'validations' do
    # Other tests......
    describe 'for email' do
      it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email).on(:create) }
    end
  end
end
```

on a model which contains the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                format: { with: VALID_EMAIL },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  # Other stuff for the model....
end
```

When I run the test it fails with the following:

```
  1) User validations for email should require case sensitive unique value for email
 Failure/Error: should validate_uniqueness_of(:email).on(:create)

   Did not expect errors to include "has already been taken" when email is set to "A",
   got errors:
   * "can't be blank" (attribute: name, value: nil)
   * "is invalid" (attribute: email, value: "A")
   * "has already been taken" (attribute: email, value: "A")
   * "can't be blank" (attribute: password, value: nil)
   * "is too short (minimum is 6 characters)" (attribute: password, value: nil)
   * "can't be blank" (attribute: password, value: nil)
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:41:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm very much at a loss as to what to do here.  The shoulda-matchers documentation is awesome, and it does state that there can be problems with creating an initial object and they suggest explicitly creating one prior to the test, that doesn't change anything in my case, I get the error either way.  I must be doing something wrong, as I said I'm not experienced with this kind of testing yet.  Any direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I had a quick check and saw that it's because you set `validates ... uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }` in your model but your spec did not specify accordingly. You could try this:

```
it { should validate_uniqueness_of(:email).case_insensitive }
```

Also, I think that `on(:create)` is not needed here.

Comment: And just like that, I owe another person from Stack Overflow a cold one.  Thank you my friend, that's all it took.